# Python 3: Repl.it invalid syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

Newbie here, for a project trying to define a dictionary prior to a loop but I keep getting an invalid syntax response when I can't see why the line is incorrect:/. Even if I define my dictionary as:

```
price = {}
```

or

```
prices = dict()
```

Both cause an error

> Incorrect syntax

Thanks for the help

[Dictionary Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAtk2.png)

Comment: The line above is missing a `)`

Comment: Post text as *text*.

Comment: Incorrect Brackets in Line json.loads

Comment: Thanks so much, lost 25 minutes for a stupid parenthesis :/. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not with the dict(). The Brackets at the end is the earlier line is missing . It Should be

```
json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(Query.format(random.random())).read())
```